# Android - access SOAP service with ws-security using client side certificate

Tags: android, soap

Android - access SOAP service with ws-security using client side x509 certificate

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/ this is only one library which i know we can use to interacting with Web Services

For dealing with security issues perhaps you should to extend `HttpTransportSE` class and configure you certificate

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy for help. I know about the ksoap2 but it doesn't provide security features. I have to come one good library but it uses the Icesoap not ksoap2. :(

Comment: U can use ksoap2 with security features. Just implements ServiceConnection interface from library as it implemented in ServiceConnectionSE but with HttpsURLConnection inside instead  of HttpURLConnection. And than setup your ServiceConnection into HttpTransportSE